# System.NullPointerException: Argument 1 cannot be null infiling set

Tags: apex, set

```
public class relatedListDynamicReferenceController {
    public List<SelectOption> selected{get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> unselected{get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> list1{get; set;}
    public List<SelectOption> list2{get;set;}
    ApexPages.StandardController acc;
    public relatedListDynamicReferenceController(ApexPages.StandardController std){
        list2= new List<SelectOption>();
        this.list1= new List<SelectOption>();

        selected =new List<SelectOption>();
        unselected = new List<SelectOption>();
       /// set1=new set<SelectOption>(optionsList());
        list1.addAll(optionsList());

    }

    public List<SelectOption> optionsList(){
        system.debug('im in');
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult result = Account.sObjectType.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.ChildRelationship> childs = result.getChildRelationships();
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

        for(Schema.ChildRelationship s: childs){     
            string str = String.valueOf(s.getRelationshipName());
            options.add(new Selectoption(str,str));
            system.debug(options);
        }
        system.debug('---------out------' + options);
        return options;
    }

    public void doAdd(){

    }

    public void doRemove(){

    }   
}
```

Comment: what line causes this exception?

Comment: ... and post the exact version of the code that has the problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In for loop at

```
string str = String.valueOf(s.getRelationshipName());
```

you must be getting null value.
I tried to debug this and in debug log for AgentWork:

> Schema.ChildRelationship[getChildSObject=AgentWork;getField=WorkItemId;getJunctionIdListNames=(); getRelationshipName=null;isCascadeDelete=true;isDeprecatedAndHidden=false;isRestrictedDelete=false;]

`getRelationshipName` is null so you are getting this error.

2)You can do null check before adding relationship to selectOption and your issue will be resolved.

```
for(Schema.ChildRelationship s: childs){
            if(s.getRelationshipName() != null)
            {   
                string str = String.valueOf(s.getRelationshipName());
                options.add(new Selectoption(str,str));
                system.debug(options);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `String.valueOf` for a null argument returns the string 'null', so while your change improves the code the root cause of the error is probably elsewhere. But yes new `SelectOption(null, null)` results in the reported error: perhaps the OP hasn't posted an exact copy of the failing code.

Comment: String s= null;
if(String.valueOf(s) == 'null')
    System.debug('String null');  by executing this I am getting nothing in debug.